# `Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted` in the virtual envinronment

Tags: python, virtualenv, sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-18.04

I tried to make a python virtualenvironment using `virtualenv` in 
I type `virtuelenv env --python=python3` 
I get an error

`PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/mnt/d/venv/bin/python3'`

So I used the command with `sudo` and therefore type `sudo virtualenv env --python=python3`

The command works this time, now I activate the environment and try to install something using pip, I get

`Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted`

I know for a fact that if use `pip` with sudo, it will install packages for the global site packages and no the site packages of the virtual environment. I want to install things to the virtual environment.

I am running ubuntu bionic on WSL, I used to run ubuntu xenial and didn't face this problem.

please advise.

Comment: I would not be surprised if this is an AppArmor "issue".

Answer (score 5):

When using WSL: Create the venv in the Linux hierarchy, not the Windows hierarchy.

Typically this means creating in `/home/YOUR_USER/` instead of `/mnt/...`.

Comment: Just a question, why does this issue occur only if attempting to create a venv in your /mnt/?

Comment: On WSL, the Windows™ filesystem is mounted in /mnt/. Like `D:\` is mounted in `/mnt/d/`. So those are two different filesystems (probably ext4 Linux side and NTFS Windows™ side). Some code somewhere may behave differently on a both filesystems, indirectly leading to the error. I have no Window box to inspect and tell more though, so it's just me guessing here. (Also executables are different in Windows™ and Linux, the former using PE and the later using ELF, so Linux probably can't use python.exe and vice-versa.)

Comment: Those are fair points, thank you for clearing things up.

Comment: I solved this by mounting the drive using the 'metadata' option so that WSL can manage the permissions on the venv files:
`sudo umount /mnt/d; sudo mount -t drvfs D: /mnt/d -o metadata`